# collapse empty cells in table rendered using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to render a table of student's where each column is a subject,
and under each column all of the student's who failed in the subject are listed.
the issue is my data is formed in a row structure rather than column.
here is an example for a table row data:

```
[{"name":"dummy1","pass":true},{"name":"dummy1","pass":false},{"name":"dummy1","pass":false}]
```

in this case there are 3 subject's and so the row length is 2 (contains 3 items).

now if the second student's row looks like this:

```
[{"name":"dummy2","pass":false},{"name":"dummy2","pass":false},{"name":"dummy2","pass":false}]
```

what happens is the first column starts with a blank cell , because first student passes the first subject, and the first name in this column will only appear in the second row.

the HTML code is this:

```
<div class="table-row" v-for="(row, i) in trows">
   <div class="item" v-for="(item, i) in row" >
      <span class="item-content" v-if="!item.pass">{{item.name}}</span>
      <span class="item-content" v-else></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

my question is, how can modify the data so that there will be no empty cell between rows when looking at it from a column perspective ?

**to emphasis :**

```
name name name        name name name
          name  == >  name name name
     name                  name name
name name name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only failed students, you can create a computed value based on original data `trows`:

```
computed: {
    failedOnlyTrows() {
        return this.trows.map(row => row.filter(({ pass }) => !!pass));
    }
}
```

Then you can use CSS:flex to display them as columns instead of rows:

```
<div class="table-row" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;" v-for="(row, i) in failedOnlyTrows">
   <div class="item" v-for="(item, i) in row" >
      <span class="item-content" v-if="!item.pass">{{item.name}}</span>
      <span class="item-content" v-else></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is not really a table, as one row doesn't have any meaning. What you want is more a series of columns, side to side.

What I would do is create a list of student who passed the first exam, and create a one column table with that list. And continue with the others exams.

To create the list for a specific exam, the i-th exam for example, you can loop through the students and if the i-th element of the array has 'pass' at true, add the name of the student to the list.

pseudo code for the i-th exam:

```
examId = i
myList = []
for studentResults in studentsResultsList
  if studentResults[i]['pass']
    myList.push(studentResults[i]['name'])
```

and create a one column table, iterating on the values in myList.
Of course, 'i' can be part of loop as well, to iterate on the exams.